# Or subspace ${(x,x): x \in \mathbb{R}})$ space $(\mathbb{r},\tau_\rightarrow)\times(\mathbb{R},\tau_\rightarrow)$ is discrete space?

Tags: general-topology

Or subspace ${((x,x): x \in \mathbb{R}})$ space $(\mathbb{R},\tau_\rightarrow)\times(\mathbb{R},\tau_\rightarrow)$ is discrete space?

$\tau_\rightarrow$ is topology of Sorgenfrey arrow

Comment: I already explained it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3688371/4280), recently. Same person (note the formulation ) or in the same class?

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal of any space $X$ is just homeomorphic to $X$ again, so **no** in this case.